# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, post

Desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando Laravel 5.2, PHP7.0, Apache2 e CentOS 7, estou tendo o seguinte erro: **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**.

No servidor local funciona normalmente... quando publico no servidor de produção ocorre o erro, segue a tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Rotas**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando alcançar (POST) a URL: */es/create*

*No arquivo de rotas:*

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'es'], function()
{
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
    {
        Route::post('create', 'SearchController@create');
    });
});
```

**View**:

```
<h1>Create</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/es/create/" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="text" name="index">
    <button type="submit">CREATE</button>        
</form>
```

Não coloquei o controller aqui porque nem chega ao controller... para na rota.

Já tentei sem o *enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"*, conforme alguns posts... mas não funcionou.

Alguém teria uma sugestão?

Obrigado!

P.S.: Encontrei vários posts em inglês, mas nenhum com a solução que preciso.

Comment: Geralmente erros relacionados ao MethodNotAllowedHttpException dão por causa da lógica do programa que está errado.Você tem que separar de forma correta os POST e GET no seu arquivo de rotas.

Comment: @Falion obrigado pelo comentário, entretanto, não ajudou muito... diante do que vê o que estaria errado? Pois estou no começo do desenvolvimento e de fato está funcionando na máquina local, o que, em minha opinião, a lógica do sistema está correta. Algum comentário sobre o código em si? À noite farei alguns testes no servidor, pois há outros sistemas rodando com *Post* habilitado no Apache... Mas estou achando muito estranho o erro. Obrigado pelo comentário novamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na *View*, a *action* da tag *form* deve constar o caminho completo da rota:

Onde está assim:

```
action="/es/create"
```

Deveria estar assim:

```
action="{{ url('/es/create') }}"
```

Segue código completo corrigido:

```
<h1>Create</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/es/create/') }}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="text" name="index">
    <button type="submit">CREATE</button>        
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Outra alternativa seria você usar a helper action, abaixo esta seu código alterado.

Ao invés disso:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Faça isso:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

E aqui seu código alterado:

```
<h1>Create</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('SearchController@create') }}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="index">
    <button type="submit">CREATE</button>        
</form>
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. O resultado é o mesmo neste caso e esse não foi o ponto da questão apresentada. Pois não era erro no token, mas sim no método.